# Android licence for app

Tags: android

Please clear up something for me. For my own interest I want to write an Android app to use on my phone, by me alone. Maybe written in Mono, or perhaps something else.

It has been suggested to me that I will need to pay a license fee for this. The Android licensing documentation hasn't cleared this up in my mind.

Do I need to implement any form of licensing or pay any license for this? I stress, the app will be for use by me alone (and maybe my wife), on my phone alone (or hers). It won't go near Google Play Store or anything like that.

Comment: If you develop with the Android SDK, it will be totally free

Comment: Do you want to develop an application for your self only? You don`t want to upload it to the Android market? or any other Market like SlideME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't submit the app to Google Play store, you don't need the licence. You can use the app or even give it to your family and friends. However, you cannot submit to the app store.

Answer (score 1):

Just install it on the phone.

Unless you're using a dev tool/SDK/library that requires a license even for non-commercial use, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

So develop it with Android SDK, it's easier and free. And distribute yourself the installer (The Android apk).